# Universal render pipeline - camera error despite assigned URP asset in quality settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I got this error - "Universal RP asset not assigned, assign one in the Graphics Settings", despite I already assigned an URP asset for each quality level(very low to ultra).[image]

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the URP in Graphics settings not quality settings[image: Graphics settings tab]